# How can I optimize this SQL query that searches nullable start or end dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

**Question**: Given a range of nullable start and end dates, what would be the best way to optimize the following query *(sample schema at the bottom)*:

```
-- Query I am trying to optimize
SELECT * FROM dateranges WHERE
    ('2014-11-10 05:59:59' > `start` AND '2014-11-03 06:00:00' <= `end`)
    OR ('2014-11-03 06:00:00' >= `start` AND `end` is null)
    OR ('2014-11-10 05:59:59' <= `end` AND `start` is null);

-- Same query but with placeholders for clarification
SELECT * FROM dateranges WHERE
    ('{endSearch}' > `start` AND '{startSearch}' <= `end`)
    OR ('{startSearch}' >= `start` AND `end` is null)
    OR ('{endSearch}' <= `end` AND `start` is null);
```

**Business conditions to be valid**:

1. Is the *name.start* >= *startSearch* AND <= *endSearch*?
2. Is the *name.start* >= *startSearch* AND *name.end* is null?
3. Is the *name.end* <= *endSearch* AND *name.start* is null?

---

Below shows *EXPLAIN* just searching for start and end:

```
1, SIMPLE, s, range, date_start_idx,date_end_idx, date_end_idx, 6, , 251, Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Below shows *EXPLAIN* with added null search:

```
1, SIMPLE, s, ALL, date_start_idx,date_end_idx, , , , 6340, Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

---

**Sample MySQL Schema**:

```
CREATE TABLE `dateranges` (
`name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
`start` DATETIME NULL,
`end` DATETIME NULL);

INSERT INTO `dateranges` (`name`,`start`,`end`) VALUES
('God',null,null),
('Dog',null,'2014-10-06'),
('Cat','2014-10-01',null),
('People','2014-10-02','2014-10-04');

ALTER TABLE `dateranges` 
ADD INDEX `index1` (`start` ASC),
ADD INDEX `index2` (`end` ASC);
```

Comment: Adding a 'start is not null' and 'end is not null' to the first condition will help eliminating all the null ones.

Comment: What does this query search for? records contained-within specified dates or records that overlap/conflict with the specified dates?

Comment: @SalmanA The query returns the id of the names for use in a content search.  Some names can have a start time for content but no end time.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the best approach is the following.  First, create an index on `start` and `end`:

```
create index idx_dateranges_start_end on dateranges(start, end)
```

Then rephrase the query using `union all`:

```
SELECT * FROM dateranges WHERE ('2014-11-10 05:59:59' > `start` AND
                                '2014-11-03 06:00:00' <= `end` AND
                                '2014-11-03 06:00:00' < `start`
                               )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dateranges WHERE ('2014-11-03 06:00:00' >= `start` AND `end` is null)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM dateranges WHERE ('2014-11-10 05:59:59' <= `end` AND `start` is null);
```

MySQL should do an index lookup for the three `where` conditions.  They are mutually exclusive, so the `union all` will not produce any duplicates.  MySQL (as well as other SQL engines) do a notoriously poor job of optimizing conditional expressions with `or`.

EDIT:

An alternative is to plug in fake dates where you would have `NULL`, something like '2000-01-01' for the start date and '2100-12-31' for the end date.  Then you can dispense with the additional clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM dateranges
WHERE ('2014-11-10 05:59:59' > `start` AND '2014-11-03 06:00:00' <= `end`)
```

Comment: I don't think that will run faster than the original query. And it's definetely not more "clear" either. This must be tested on a big table.

Comment: +1 Yes, absolutely. Also valid for IN clause. Myself have a bad experience with SELECT MIN(x) FROM WHERE someid IN (1,2) on SQL Server.

Comment: I will add this to the original question.  There are indexes on start and end.  But the query still says it is using a where clause.

Comment: @CGSmith105 . . . You need a relatively large table for MySQL to use the indexes.  If you table only has a few hundred -- or even a few thousand -- rows, it will probably find the scan to be faster.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That makes sense that MySQL would switch.  Would you still use a union with the indexes?

Comment: @CGSmith105 . . . I'm thinking about this problem and now I'm not so confident that the indexes will help that much.  Do you have a separate list of the names that are allowed?  And, are there rules about overlaps?  For instance, there are no overlaps for a given name.

Comment: @CGSmith105 . . . I just added an additional condition on the first query which should help with index usage.  I think the first query is the problematic one in terms of the index.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume that you want to select all rows that overlap the date range **[2014-11-03 06:00:00, 2014-11-10 06:00:00)**, end dates are exclusive. The query that selects such records is:

```
SELECT * FROM dateranges
WHERE '2014-11-10 06:00:00' > `start`
AND `end` > '2014-11-03 06:00:00'
```

In order to deal with NULL dates I suggest that you make the date columns NOT NULL and store unrealistic values (e.g. `1000-01-01` for start and `9999-12-31` for end) instead of NULL.

---

Having said that, you can check for NULLs using an OR clause and still use indexes using this query:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM dateranges AS a
INNER JOIN dateranges AS b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE ('2014-11-10 06:00:00' > a.`start` OR a.`start` IS NULL)
AND (b.`end` > '2014-11-03 06:00:00' OR b.`end` IS NULL)
```

This query can utilize two indexes since the AND-OR clauses are grouped strategically. **HOWEVER**, if MySQL chooses not to use the indexes for some reason (e.g. because of insufficient cardinality) then this query will perform much worse than the no-join version.

---

Also create indexes on both start and end dates. If you create a composite index on (start, end) then you should also create (end, start) index. MySQL will choose either index depending on the "constant" dates in your query.